# How does the MERN stack get put together?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, react-router, mern

For MERN stack, React rejects the MVC paradigm. I do not  comprehend how mongoDB(mongoose) models work with routes? Do routes behave the same as a controller would? And how does that tie into the frontend? After digging through many GitHub projects, I've seen src folder, server folder, model folder and routes, but i am still confused on how the entirety of MERN stack comes together. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about why they are used together or how they work together?

Comment: I used Nodejs, ExpressJS, and MongoDB for server side to build restful web services. In Reactjs, you can use axios, fetch to interact with your server side

Comment: @Khang How they work together ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically In MERN stack we use React.js to build client side frontend and Node.js to build backend api endpoints which is usually connecting databases whether is sql or nosql to perform several operations and in node.js it get a request from client side and give response according to request. his is quite simple architecture.